# Why does $\frac{d}{dt}e^{X+tY} |_{t=0}$ depend linearly on $Y$ with $X$ fixed?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'm studying the proof of Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula from Brian Hall's book Lie Groups, Lie Algebras and Representations. I am stuck at this part:
[image]

I don't get why continuity of exp implies that the directional derivative depends linearly on Y with X fixed. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me that it is a simple consequence of the fact that, by definition, the derivative is the linear approximation of the function at a point.

Comment: @EmilioNovati : you meant the differential more than the derivative, and don't you think continuous differentiability implies that the differential at some point is a bounded linear operator (in case of $X,Y$ belong to some Hilbert or Banach space) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that $$\frac{d}{dt}e^{X+tY} = \frac{d}{dt}\sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{(X+tY)^k}{k!} = \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{\frac{d}{dt}(X+tY)^k}{k!}$$ with (because of non-commutativity) $$\frac{d}{dt}(X+tY)^k = \sum_{m=0}^{k-1} (X+tY)^{m} Y (X+tY)^{k-1-m}$$ and at $t=0$  : $$\frac{d}{dt}{(X+tY)^k}_{|t=0} = \sum_{m=0}^{k-1} X^{m} Y X^{k-1-m}$$ and $$\frac{d}{dt} {e^{X+tY}}_{|t=0} =\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{k!}\sum_{m=0}^{k-1} X^{m} Y X^{k-1-m}$$

now the general case : if $f$ is continuously differentiable at $X$, then $$f(X+tY) = f(X) + g(t Y) + \mathcal{O}(\|t Y\|^{1 +\epsilon})$$ where $g$, the differential at $X$, is some (bounded, because of the continuity) $\mathbb{R}$-linear operator, i.e. $g(tY) = t g(Y)$ and $$\frac{d}{dt}{f(X+tY)}_{|t=0} = g(Y)$$ hence the directional derivative (at some point) of any $C^1$ function is bounded $\mathbb{R}$-linear in the direction.

Comment: What if $f$? An entire function?

Comment: no in the neighborhood of $X$ it is any locally analytic function plus a residual term $\mathcal{O}(\|t Y\|^{1+\epsilon})$ : i.e. a $C^1$ function, it is not correct ?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp : I precised $C^1 \implies$ the directional derivative is $\mathbb{R}$-linear and bounded in the direction. is it why you asked if $f$ was entire ?

Comment: Thanks. For the general part, your argument acted as a hint and I think I have a somewhat clearer explanation. Let $g: \mathbb{R} \to M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be $g(t) = X+tY$. Then $\frac{d}{dt} f(X+tY) |_{t=0} = \frac{d}{dt}f(g(t))|_{t=0}$. By the chain rule, this is $f'(g(0)).g'(0) = f'(X).Y$. I still don't see where the _continuous_ differentiability of $f$ is used though.

Comment: I don't think I can do this. I am confused again.

Comment: it is not $f'(X)$ times $Y$ but $f'(X)(Y)$ : as I wrote,  your $f'(X)$ (I called it $g$, not the derivative but the Jacobian  at $X$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant ) is a $\mathbb{R}$ linear operator, hence if $Y$ is complex : $\frac{d}{dt}f(X+tY)_{|t=0} = g_X(Re(Y),Im(Y))$ (try with matrices, and the functions $X \to X^2$ or $X \to X X^*$)

Comment: @Seven :  and I think the continuity of the differential is useful if $X,Y$ are linear operators on infinite dimensional vector (Banach or Hilbert) spaces : it tells us the Jacobian is a bounded linear operator (whenever $X,Y$ are bounded)

Comment: I think I have got the subtlety. When I write $f'(X).Y$, $Y$ is no longer an $n \times n$ matrix but an $n^2$ length column vector, and it is acted upon by the $n^2 \times n^2$ matrix $f'(X)$.

Comment: @Seven : yes. and you saw the difference between $X \to X^2$ and $X \to X X^*$ as functions on the complex matrices ? the former is complex differentiable (holomorphic) while the latter is only real differentiable (hence $f'(X)$ is a linear operator of $Re(Y)$ and $Im(Y)$ separately, not of $Re(Y) + i Im(Y)$ as a whole)

Comment: $X \to \exp(X)$ or your question is holomorphic : it is analytic in $X$ (as $X \to X^2$)

Comment: @user1952009 I asked because $\exp$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb C$ and you can use the analytic functional calculus to define $\exp(A)$. However, I realized later that your $f$ is probably $C^1$ from $\mathbb K^{n\times n}$ to itself (or from an open set), right? This is then totally unrelated to functional calculus so that my question is irrelevant.